# mathtools bug with aligned

Tags: compiling, mathtools

The following code does not compile

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\DeclarePairedDelimiter\abs{\lvert}{\rvert}
\begin{document}
 \[\aligned
    &\abs{X}
 \endaligned\]
 \end{document}
```

If I add a character before the alignment character like `a & \abs{X}`, the code compiles

Is this expected? Is there a better workaround?

Comment: `aligned` is an environment. Use it as such and it will work `:-)`

Comment: `\[\begin{aligned}
    &\abs{X}
 \end{aligned}\]`

Comment: Plus this has nothing to do with `mathtools`, `aligned` comes from `amsmath` which `mathtools` loads. Though it is interesting why `&` makes `\aligned` fail.

Comment: The code `\[\aligned & X  \endaligned \]` compiles. So it's the combinations of `aligned` and `\DeclarePairedDelimiter`. However, using the `aligned` environment as suggested by @campa and @Zarko suggested resolves this issue.

Comment: Would you (@campa or @Zarko) add an answer to the question? Or is there a duplicat question?

Comment: @Bobyandbob I had started writing one but I stopped because I could not understand what is going wrong in the interaction between `\aligned` and `\abs`.